# Bitwise operation issue in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Is there a simple bitwise operation (including addition, mod etc) which can produce the following output and similar for cur=6...

This is for ordering the L0 reference list with field pictures in x264.

```
field_ref_dist( cur, ref );

f( 1, 0 ) = 0

f( 2, 1 ) = 1
f( 2, 0 ) = 0

f( 3, 2 ) = 1
f( 3, 1 ) = 0
f( 3, 0 ) = 2

f( 4, 3 ) = 1
f( 4, 2 ) = 0
f( 4, 1 ) = 3
f( 4, 0 ) = 2

f( 5, 4 ) = 1
f( 5, 3 ) = 0
f( 5, 2 ) = 3
f( 5, 1 ) = 2
f( 5, 0 ) = 4
```

Comment: With this small of a number of values, you should consider just building a lookup table.  With processor caches, it should be really fast.

Comment: It's not speed critical but I'm sure there's a nice way of doing it. cur can reach up to 32.

Comment: I would definitely use a lookup-table for this, as it would result in code that's much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I extrapolated the values correctly, but if I did,

```
unsigned field_ref_dist(unsigned cur, unsigned ref) {
    return ((cur - ref - 1) & ~1u) + ((cur - ref) & !!ref);
}
```

does it:

```
f(1, 0) = 0

f(2, 1) = 1
f(2, 0) = 0

f(3, 2) = 1
f(3, 1) = 0
f(3, 0) = 2

f(4, 3) = 1
f(4, 2) = 0
f(4, 1) = 3
f(4, 0) = 2

f(5, 4) = 1
f(5, 3) = 0
f(5, 2) = 3
f(5, 1) = 2
f(5, 0) = 4

f(6, 5) = 1
f(6, 4) = 0
f(6, 3) = 3
f(6, 2) = 2
f(6, 1) = 5
f(6, 0) = 4

f(7, 6) = 1
f(7, 5) = 0
f(7, 4) = 3
f(7, 3) = 2
f(7, 2) = 5
f(7, 1) = 4
f(7, 0) = 6

f(8, 7) = 1
f(8, 6) = 0
f(8, 5) = 3
f(8, 4) = 2
f(8, 3) = 5
f(8, 2) = 4
f(8, 1) = 7
f(8, 0) = 6

f(9, 8) = 1
f(9, 7) = 0
f(9, 6) = 3
f(9, 5) = 2
f(9, 4) = 5
f(9, 3) = 4
f(9, 2) = 7
f(9, 1) = 6
f(9, 0) = 8
```

it might even be as fast as a lookup table.

Disregarding the case `ref == 0` and `cur` odd for the moment, the values can naturally be grouped in pairs `(2*k, 2*k+1)`, and the values depend only on the difference `cur - ref` there.

Swapping these pairs we'd have just `cur - ref - 1`. So to get the smaller value of these pairs - `2*k` - we can just mask off the least significant bit, thus

```
(cur - ref - 1) & ~1u
```

Now, the order of the pairs is actually such that the larger (odd) value comes for the smaller (odd) difference, so we add `1` if the difference is odd,

```
((cur - ref - 1) & ~1u) + ((cur - ref) & 1u)
```

That works for all cases except `cur` odd and `ref == 0`, in which case the value must be `cur - 1` (which then is even, hence the `& ~1u` does not change it) and not `((cur - ref - 1) & ~1u) + ((cur - ref) & 1u)`.

So for that special case, the addend should be `0` and not `1`. We get that from `(cur - ref) & 0`, thus we need an operation that produces `1` for nonzero `ref` and `0` for `ref == 0` [If `cur` is even, the difference is also even, and `((cur - ref) & 1u) == 0`, so that isn't touched by replacing `1u` with `0` for `ref == 0`]. That is achieved by `!!ref`.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I've added an explanation of how to arrive at that expression.